# How to translate "and" into "et" within a French bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, french

I have a document in french language that uses bib references. This is why is use the `babel` package with the `french` option. However, the bibliographical references still contain the "and" word when there are several authors. I do not know how to translate this into "et".

For example, this is the content of mydoc.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

J'aime citer \cite{Golub1996}.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliographie}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mydoc}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography contains:

```
@Book{Golub1996,
  author =    {Golub, Gene H. and Van Loan, Charles. F.},
  title =     {Matrix computations, 3d Edition, Volume 1},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
  year =      {1996},
}
```

I used:

```
pdflatex mydoc
bibtex mydoc
pdflatex mydoc
pdflatex mydoc
```

This produces:

[image: A bibligraphy with "and" statements instead of "et"]

I would like to see "Gene H. Golub ***et*** Charles. F. Van Loan." instead.

I tried to apply the methods presented at:

[https://www.irit.fr/~Alain.Crouzil/jaffre/LOGICIELS/LATEX_BIBTEX/bibtex1.html](https://www.irit.fr/%7EAlain.Crouzil/jaffre/LOGICIELS/LATEX_BIBTEX/bibtex1.html)

but this produced lots of errors that I was not able to fix.

Comment: When I used BibTeX in the past, I needed a French BibTeX style file (.bst) for this, IIRC. Nowadays, I think it works out of the box if you use BibLaTeX (package) and biber (external program).

Comment: There is a version of the plain style translated in French here, I believe: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~perrut/plain-fr.bst

Comment: You should not indicate "3d Edition, Volume 1" in the title (since this information is not part of the actual title). Instead, you should try: `@Book{Golub1996,author={Golub, Gene H. and Van Loan, Charles. F.},title={Matrix computations},edition= {3},volume={1},publisher={Johns Hopkins University Press},year={1996}}` Translation in French will then apply to the edition field as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find a French style, it's much easier to use `biblatex`:

```
% compile with (pdf)latex + biber + (pdf)latex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@Book{Golub1996,
  author =    {Golub, Gene H. and Van Loan, Charles. F.},
  title =     {Matrix computations, 3d Edition, Volume 1},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
  year =      {1996},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

J'aime citer \cite{Golub1996}.

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliographie} % fait par heading=bibintoc ci-dessous
\printbibliography[title=Bibliographie,heading=bibintoc]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the title is wrong and thus "3d Edition" is not properly translated.

Comment: Yes, I just copied the title from the OP. This shouldn't be in the title, but in `edition={}` and `volume={}`.